# Complex integrations

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate integrals

$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{z^2 e^z}{2z+i} dz $$

and

$$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{e^z}{z^2+z} dz $$

These are simple integrals to do with cauchy integral theorem right?

First one.

\begin{align}
\frac{z^2 e^z}{2z+i}&=\frac 12\frac{z^2 e^z}{z-(-\frac i2)} \\
\oint_{|z|=1} &=\frac 12 \cdot 2\pi i\cdot\left( (-\frac i2)^2 e^{-\frac i2}\right) \\
&=\frac{-\pi i}{4e^{ \frac i2}}
\end{align}

And the second. 
\begin{align}
\frac{e^z}{z^2 +z}&=\frac{e^z}{z(z-(-1))} \\
\oint_{|z|=2}&=2 \pi i\cdot \left( \frac{e^z}{z}_{z=-1}+\frac{e^z}{z+1}_{z=0} \right) \\
\oint_{|z|=2} &=2\pi i\cdot\left( \frac{e^{-1}}{-1}+ \frac{e^0}{0-(-1)}\right) \\
&=\frac{-2\pi i}{e}+2 \pi i
\end{align}

Comment: For the first, you have a mistake in the last step. Check it again. For the second, you missed that the singularity at $z = -1$ also lies in the interior of the circle. Doing a partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{z^2+z}$ is probably the easiest way to get the result.

Comment: Edited my first and second answers. What do you think?

Comment: Closer, but still not right. You have a problem with your minuses, and for the second, how do you get the middle equation? [It looks suspicious.]

Comment: Isn't it $\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz = 2 \pi i \cdot f(z_0)$. And in the second we have two singularities $0$ and $-1$ and for those the functions are $f_1 (z)=\frac{e^z}{z+1}$ and $f_2 (z) = \frac{e^z}{z}$

Comment: In the first I don't know what I'm doing wrong. There is one singularity inside the unit circle $-i/2$ and $f(z) = z^2 e^z $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first computation is correct until

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\pi i\cdot \left(\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)^2e^{-i/2}\right).$$

Then you make some computation errors.

$$\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{i^2}{4} = -\frac{1}{4},$$

so we get

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\pi i \cdot\left(-\frac{1}{4} e^{-i/2}\right) = -\frac{\pi i}{4} e^{-i/2} = -\frac{\pi i}{4e^{i/2}},$$

you have one minus sign too much at the outermost level, and when you moved the exponential term to the denominator, you forgot to change the sign of the exponent.

The second result is correct, but it looks as though the way you chose is invalid.

> Isn't it $\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz = 2 \pi i \cdot f(z_0)$. And in the second we have two singularities 0 and −1 and for those the functions are $f_1(z) = \frac{e^z}{z+1}$ and $f_2(z) = \frac{e^z}{z}$.

Note that the integral formula $\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz = 2 \pi i \cdot f(z_0)$ requires that $f$ be holomorphic on the entire region enclosed by $C$, and neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ are holomorphic on the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 2\}$.

It works if you replace the contour $\lvert z\rvert = 2$ by two circles winding around one of the singularities each, which by Cauchy's integral theorem you can do, since the cycles are homologous in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,-1\}$.

Of course, if you may use it, you can just invoke the residue theorem, and compute the residue of $\frac{e^z}{z(z+1)}$ in $0$ and in $-1$, and add them. Before that point, the probably best way to handle the integral is a partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{1}{z(z+1)} = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z+1}$$

and then the integral becomes

$$\oint_{\lvert z\rvert = 2} \frac{e^z}{z} - \frac{e^z}{z+1}\,dz,$$

where each summand is easily evaluated by Cauchy's integral formula.